# Ionic 5 - ngfor not diplaying on component

Tags: angular, ionic5

I'm going crazy, i've created a new component and he's working fine. Now i would like to use this on two pages.

Then i've created a component module (/components/all-components.module.ts) like this :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TagsComponent } from './tags/tags.component';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';


@NgModule({
  imports: [IonicModule],
  declarations: [
    TagsComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    TagsComponent
  ]
})

export class AllComponentsModule {}
```

I've added on app.module.ts the AllComponentsModule and on my 2 pages module i have added same.

Now, my component work fine when i'm displaying text or variable, my console.log return the data, but if i use `*ngFor` nothing appear.

Finally, here's my component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tags',
  templateUrl: './tags.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tags.component.scss'],
})
export class TagsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() userTags: any;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.userTags);
  }
}
```

And the view:

```
<p>hi</p>
<div *ngFor="let tag of userTags">
  <p>{{tag?.name}}</p>
</div>
```

[image: screen]

Comment: ngFor needs to be an array, not any. try `@Input() userTags: [];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i don't understand why but if i use a module to store all of components. On my `all-components.module.ts` i have to put the `CommonModule` to interpret `*ngFor`, `*ngIf`, etc.

With CommonModule import all working fine !

Here's the code updated:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TagsComponent } from './tags/tags.component';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [
    TagsComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    TagsComponent
  ]
})

export class AllComponentsModule {}
```

Comment: From my experience, the problem could also occur if you used the routing module for lazy loading instead of the module